# Pipe : gunzip files and concatenate

Tags: pipe

I feel like this should be simple. I have a directory with >1000 gzip-ed files. I'd like to gunzip them all and concatenate.

Running `gzip -dk *.gz | cat > output.file` produces the following error: `Too many levels of symbolic links`

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zcat -- *.gz > output.file`

Apart from that `gzip -dk *.gz` does not what you expect. It will create a decompressed copy of each file and not print them. You rather want `gzip -dc` or `gunzip -c`.

Comment: How to pipe directly and concatenate? Of course, I could decompress all files first and then concatenate in a single file, but I was thinking there could be a faster process.

Comment: ? The `zcat` example should do that. There is no need for a extra pipe or `cat`. `zcat` prints the decompressed content directly, in this example into output.file.

Comment: My bad - I didn't get what zcat is doing at first.

I might be overreaching, but another question. Is there a way to iterate zcat over let's say 500 files first, then run the next 500 and so until the end? I want to create few manageable files instead of a giant single file.